# hive sql select from table with prioritized condition

Tags: sql, hiveql

I want to select `name` and `nametype` from a table called `names`, but prioritized on the `nametype`.

```
table names

name        nametype    address    id
simon           01       xx         1
simon           02       xx         2 
simon           03       xx         3 
karen           01       xx         4
william         03       xx         5 
william         01       xx         6
william         02       xx         7
```

I want to write a query that selects the `name` with either `nametype` = 01 or 02 or 03, in that sort order.
I only want the row with `nametype` = 01, the other 2 rows should not be
selected.

How can I achieve this in sql, I need to find out how to mark a name already selected.

Comment: Please show the results that you want.  Also fix the question.  Presumably, `banetype` is really `nametype`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to figure it out my self using coalesce

```
pseudocode:

if nametypes = OECD207
     select row
 elseif nametypes = OECD203
     select row
 elseif nametypes =OECD204
     select row
end if
```

OECD207
OECD203
OECD204
...
being the prioritized list

```
select
navn
, coalesce(OECD207, OECD203, OECD204, ...) as nametype 
from
(
select
navn
, max(case when nametype = "OECD207" then nametype else null end) as OECD207
, max(case when nametype = "OECD203" then nametype else null end) as OECD203
, max(case when nametype = "OECD204" then nametype else null end) as OECD204
...
from ...
group by
navn
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want rows with `01`, then use `where`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.nametype = '01';
```

If you want rows with the minimum value of `nametype` (which seems to be the intention of your question), then use window functions and `where`.  One method uses `min()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, min(t.nametype) over (partition by name) as min_nametype
      from t
     ) t
where nametype = min_nametype;
```

Comment: Hi gordon my task is, to select the name with  nametype. My task is select the name with nametype in (02,01,03 ) but it should only select the name once. if the prioritized list is 02,01,03 meaning if simon exists with nametype 02 select or if exists with nametype 01 select or if exists with 03 select. so the result should always result in that only one row or name is selected.

Comment: @havmaage . . . If your sort order is not 01, 02, 03, then you have a different question.  I would suggest that you ask another question with more description about what you really want to accomplish.